# Increment an integer by calling a hashtable value in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

You'd think it'd be easy.

I have the following code:

```
key_handlers=collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)
key_handlers['+']=operator.iadd(tickrate,1)
key_handlers['-']=operator.iadd(tickrate,-1)
```

Tickrate is, of course, a global int. Later on, I have something along the lines of this (I've lost the original code by now, having replaced it with an elif chain):

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    key_handlers[event.unicode]()
```

...which doesn't work, because iadd only in-place-add-s to mutable types, and ints are immutable. You can't assign things in lambdas, and I'd rather not have a whole function to add one to a number. How can I go about this without sacrificing Pythonic-ness?

Comment: But you cannot increment an immutable. You *always* have to replace the value. So your best approach is to have your `key_handlers` methods *return the new value* and use that return value

Comment: The alternative is for `tickrate` to be custom object that supports increment and decrement operations you can call on it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Alas, I can't do the former because key_handlers is itself being accessed by lambdas. The latter would work, but it seems awfully odd to have to define a whole new number class just to have a number that goes up and down :\

Comment: @Schilcote well it's that or rewrite Python to have mutable integers.

Comment: Or just write a `increment_tick` function taking an integer as a parameter containing `global tickrate; tickrate += i`.  And use `functools.partial` to assign it to dict with `1` or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can stage the `defaultdict` with a default value of your choice. For instance:

```
from collections import defaultdict
key_handlers = defaultdict(lambda : tickrate)
```

But, from the example above, what I think you really want is a `dict` of methods that update either global state. This is expanding from the comment from @utdemir above:

```
global tickrate
key_kandlers = {'+': lambda : 1, '-': lambda : -1}
func = key_handlers.get(event.type, None)
if func is not None:
    tickrate += func()
```

The example above limits you to just manipulating the `tickrate` state, so you likely want something more robust. But the general form above where the `event.type` is used to fetch a function is quite useful.