# Changing the value of a variable stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm struggling to think of another simple way around it.

My code (the relevant bits):

```
import file2

sliderData = [{'name': 'Number of mountains', 'variable': file2.NUMMOUNTAINS},
              {'name': 'Number of trees', 'variable': file2.NUMTREES}

for i in range(len(self.sliders)):  # self.sliders is a list of Slider() objects
    self.sliderData[i]['variable'] = self.sliders[i].update()  # update() returns an int

print int(file2.NUMMOUNTAINS)
```

I can't work out how to make it update the variable stored in `sliderData[i]['variable']` (i.e. changing `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS` itself).  It seems to just change the value stored in the dictionary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS` is an `int` or `float`, note that both types are *immutable*, i.e. cannot be changed in place.

Therefore when you assign the value returned by `self.sliders[i].update()` to `self.sliderData[i]['variable']`, this **doesn't** change `file2.NUMMOUNTAIN` but instead assigns the dictionary reference to *a different object*.

A minimal example to display this:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> id(d['a'])
1751629384
>>> d['a'] += 1
>>> d
{'a': 2}
>>> id(d['a'])
1751629400 # different 'id' means different object
```

You will have to explicitly alter the value of the attribute, e.g.

```
file2.NUMMOUNTAIN = self.sliderData[0]['variable']
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. So there's no way to do this without explicitly typing out file2.NUMMOUNTAINS? I was hoping to iterate over a large number of sliders which would each control a different variable, it'd be a much more elegant solution if I could do so without explicitly altering it in the way you describe. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: You would have to switch the object attributes to a mutable type - for example, you could store the value in a single-element list, or create a custom mutable numeric type. You have a similar problem to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24250934/3001761).

Answer (score 1):

You should add to file2 some kind of method to to make the update, because what you're doing in that code is changing the value (of key 'variable') in the dictionary.

For example you can have in file2 a method that receives a key name and a value, and then change the real value you want to change

```
class File2:

def __init__(self):
    self.NUMMOUNTAINS = 0
    self.NUMTREES = 0
    pass

def setValue(self, key, value):
    if key == 'Number of mountains':
         self.NUMMOUNTAINS = value
    elif key == 'Number of trees':
         self.NUMMTREES = value
```

Then in your actual code:

```
for i in range(len(self.sliders)):  # self.sliders is a list of Slider() objects
    file2.setValue(self.sliderData[i]['name'], self.sliders[i].update())  # update() returns an int
```

Anyways, this is a poor structure, and if you need to scale it (like having much more elements in the dictionary) it'll be hard and error prone.

Answer (score -1):

It seems `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS` is `int` so in dictionary you get copy of value from `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS` - not reference to variable `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS`

`self.sliderData[i]['variable']` and `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS` are indenpendent variables.

When you change `self.sliderData[i]['variable']` it doesn't change `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS`.
When you change `file2.NUMMOUNTAINS` it doesn't change  `self.sliderData[i]['variable']`.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect - the dictionary initially references *the same object* as the instance attribute (it actually does have "reference to variable" not "copy of value"). Names in Python are references to objects, it's the subsequent assignment that doesn't alter the original object.